# How to handle accessory button tap on iOS in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

There's a `AccessoryButtonTapped` method to override in table view delegate, but it's not clear how to perform that in a `ListViewRenderer` subclass?

So I can display a disclosure indicator, but can't handle tap on it.

```
public class ContactCellRenderer : ImageCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (
        Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (item, reusableCell, tv);
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have just to implement the method `AccessoryButtonTapped` in your renderer.

```cs
public class ContactListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer, IUITableViewDelegate
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.WeakDelegate = this; // or. Control.Delegate
        }
    }

    public virtual void AccessoryButtonTapped(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // accessory tapped
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sven-Michael, I'll try that. Is it safe to set `WeakDelegate`? :) I supposed it's already set to some default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sven-Michael, you can enrich his code by creating a inheritance of your `ListView` (if you do not already have one) and add a `Delegate` to it like this:

```
public class AccessoryListView : ListView
{
   public delegate void OnAccessoryTappedDelegate();

   public OnAccessoryTappedDelegate OnAccessoryTapped { get; set; }
}
```

Now from your custom renderer - don't forget to set it to your new inherited `ListView` - call the delegate

```
public class ContactListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer, IUITableViewDelegate
{
    private AccessoryListView _formsControl;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AccessoryListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.WeakDelegate = this; // or. Control.Delegate
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
           _formsControl = e.NewElement;
    }

    public virtual void AccessoryButtonTapped(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // accessory tapped
        if (_formsControl.OnAccessoryTapped != null)
           _formsControl.OnAccessoryTapped();
    }
}
```

You can of course add some parameters in there to supply your shared code with more data. With this you do have some platform specific code, but you get back to your shared code 'as soon as possible' making your code more reusable.

Another sample of this with a Map control can be found [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/UnlockNativeFormsSample).